# Selenium ElementClickInterceptedException - Intercepted/Receive same element

Tags: selenium

I try to click on a button, but I get this error:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: 

    element click intercepted: Element 
      <button class="ogOEj4x-0BpDZWeccJwxx s1vteny2-12 fJWqQW">...</button> 
        is not clickable at point (1108, 559).

    Other element would receive the click: 
      <button class="ogOEj4x-0BpDZWeccJwxx s1vteny2-12 fJWqQW">...</button>
```

In HTML is only one button with that `class`.

So what is the point of this error? Can't click on button because it will receive the click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to use clicking by Actions

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. P.S.: Also now work with my code. I'm still confused.